# Standalone Title Page

Tags: xetex, titles, standalone

I'm trying to create a title page that I can add to documents I create with `standalone` in `xelatex`. This basic code compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
\begin{titlepage}        
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

However just changing the document type to `standalone`,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}    
\begin{titlepage}        
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

results in the following error:

```
Improper \prevdepth. \begin{titlepage}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm the `standalone` author. Note that `standalone` with its default setting is designed for boxed content like `tikzpictures` etc. and not for paragraph content. If you need that, please add the `varwidth` class option or switch to the `preview` option which uses the `preview` package internally, which also allows paragraph content.

Comment: When I read `standalone tile page` I would not see it as using the `standalone` class, but rather be a document in its own right, just a normal article with `\pagestyle{empty}` in the preamble to remove all headers and footers. It is quite common to make the title page as a separate document, so `standalone` might just be a simple confusion in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Through trial and error while consulting the [documentation](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf), it seems that adding `pstricks` option solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}    
\begin{titlepage}        
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use the titlepage environment? You don't need it, it has no purpose.

Comment: @Johannes_B For some reason, without the `titlepage` ignores the geometry.

Comment: I would use a normal document, an empty page (no page number) and just do https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Integrating_the_title_page